# Angular 2 Client Side Errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I am just new to Typescript and Angular 2 and I was wondering what approach would be best for logging client side errors so that if an issue happened in production I would be able to find out what the method was that failed and what error was thrown.

The backend off the app is written in C# and connected to a SQL Server DB.  Data is retrieved via WebAPI Calls.

Any server side errors are currently logged to the DB.  I was thinking of writing an Typescript errorLoggingService which would call an ErrorLoggingController API which would then log the Error to the DB?

Does this seem like a sound approach or is there a better way of doing this?

An example current Typescript method I have is below:

```
public getCustomerData(customerId: number, year: number) {
   let apiUrl = this.myApiMethod;
   let urlConcat = apiUrl + '/' + customerId + '/' + year + '/';

   return this.http.get(urlConcat)
      .map((response: Response) => <boolean> response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
}

public handleError(error: Response) {
   console.log(Error Handler Method Hit);
   //this is where I would call to the Error logging service
   // which would make an API call to log the error to db
   //this.errorLoggingService.logClientError("Build Error Message");
   return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server Error');
}
```

Comment: Why would you send the error from the server to the backend and then again to the server? Just modify your logger in a way that all occured errors are getting logged in the DB. (logging in files > logging in DB)

Comment: Sounds straightforward as a service, but I've been juggling back and forth on this one. A simple global script bundled into the app that makes the log call can save a lot of that providing/importing/injecting boilerplate (for example, an assert implementation). I don't care if it's in the app zone, etc. It'd be nice somehow if Component, as-is without any modification other than a top-level configuration, allowed you to make the functionality available on-board throughout.

Comment: @Sandrooco - not sure ehat you mean why would i be sending the error from server to backend...i am asking about logging client side errors that would occur in an end users browser to the db so i have a log of them

Comment: `.catch(this.handleError);` is chained to a call to your server - if ANY error triggers this function, it's the error from your server.

Comment: @Sandrooco..so would you suggest having no client side error logging?  Also I dont necessaily agree log files are greater than logging in a DB.  Ive used both and found it easier to query a db than grep up to 500 log files

Comment: At work we use sentry and it works like a dream. I had a version I wrote myself and there's a surprising amount complexity. With sentry I've got a nice web ui and release tracking and sourcemaps and it was pretty easy to set up. Also, we're not even close to crossing the free tier limit (but I'm probably going to get a pro subscription just to support them). I'm sounding like a shill but forreal, there are companies that do this for cheap, and you should check them out.

Comment: @Alex - will do sone reading on that..cheers

Comment: Hey, was wondering if you ever found a solution to your question? I am trying to do the exact same thing. Any resources or experience you could share would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: @KyleVassella - I updated the answer with what I used and a link to another one that looks pretty useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using jsnlog - http://jsnlog.com/

Usersnap also looks like a useful tool - https://usersnap.com/e1/classic-008

Comment: Thanks. Curious what made you go with a third party framework. Did you try without the framework first, and it was too much? Or was this just preference?
I'm trying without a framework right now but may resort to the tool you used if I hit road blocks.