# Angular Client Side Errors Log to Server

Tags: angular

I want to log to client side angular errors to Server, so I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43530156/angular-2-client-side-errors) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51431873/send-angular-6-client-side-errors-to-web-api-for-logging/51431986#51431986) stackoverflow answers and implemented a service
which makes a http call server. For now the `logError` method is getting hit but http call is not made to server.

```
export class AngularLoggerService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

logError(error: Error) {
   console.log(error.stack); // line is printed to console
   this.http.post('/angular/log', {
     message: error.stack
   });
 }
}
```

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdmfqg)

[image]

Comment: base url missing in your service please check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this.http.post` returns an observable unless you use `.subscribe` method in the observable, the server call wont be made change your code as follows

```
export class AngularLoggerService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    logError(error: Error) {
       console.log(error.stack); // line is printed to console
       this.http.post('/angular/log', {
         message: error.stack
       }).subscribe((res) => console.log(res));
     }
    }
```

Comment: Ahh, so you pointed the error quick, my bad I forgot the basic step to subscribe it!

Comment: Well, i too experienced the same issue. so now i give you the solution. life is about stop doing same mistakes..

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the baseUrl (server URL) in your `post` method and also `subscribe` to that `Observable` so that you will get the response back about error log successfully or not. Here is a solution.

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AngularLoggerService {

  baseUrl = "https://yourserver.com"
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  logError(error: Error) {
    console.log(error.stack);
    this.http.post(this.baseUrl +'/angular/log', {
      message: error.stack
    }).subscribe( (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

[**Here is Forked Stackblitz solution**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tuw4pn?file=src/app/angularlogger.service.ts)

Hope this will help!